# How to achieve reliable push message service?

Tags: android, ios, push-notification

Since I want to build reliable communication in mobile apps, could I get push failed reports(maybe device is offline) from the third party push services (C2DM, APN, urban airship) ?
Or We need to build it by ourselves?

Comment: Notifications sent to Android devices can be quite unreliable (https://eladnava.com/google-cloud-messaging-extremely-unreliable/). Consider Pushy (https://pushy.me/), a highly-reliable push notification gateway that aims to solve this by utilizing an underlying MQTT socket connection to deliver notifications. Full disclosure - I founded Pushy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The intended purpose of [Android C2DM](https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/) is to be a battery-saving way for your server app to signal the mobile device that it wants to start reliable communications.

You can structure your message so that each new C2DM encompasses everything that has occurred since the last two-way interaction with the server (i.e., "come and get whatever I've got").  Your failed delivery report is implicit in the mobile device not responding promptly (you can do this because you know C2DM activates your app with an Intent).

Is that really any worse than guaranteed delivery of each message in a lossy medium?  Okay, it's worse in that you also have to implement a primary communication method.  But you had to do that anyway because C2DM is inbound-only, right?

Comment: Thanks! I think it is suitable for any push-based service which is not reliable. I will evaluate each answer and award the best one for me.

Answer (score 2):

As Vinay says, MQTT may offer you the feature you desire. When a client connects to the server, it can register a "last will and testament" message with the server. If the client disconnects unexpectedly, the server sends this message to the topic it was instructed to do.

In this scheme, your client could send a message "online" to something like client//status and register the message "offline" as a LWT for the same topic. You could then have a server local client that listened to the topic client/+/status and it would know which clients were online and which offline.

I would suggest that the tokudu demo isn't the best place to look. This blog post by Dale Lane gives insight into using MQTT on Android: http://dalelane.co.uk/blog/?p=1599 and there is a review of MQTT power usage (again on Android) at http://stephendnicholas.com/archives/219

There are client implementations to suit both IOS and Android, see http://mqtt.org/software

Comment: Thanks for response! Thumb up first for your answer.

Comment: And here's another power usage comparison, this time to https: http://stephendnicholas.com/archives/1217

Answer (score 2):

No one service does not provide reports about failed pushes.

**Failed push report makes little sence with APN/C2DM/Helium**

All services are aimed to deliver the push-message under all circumstances.
If device is offline now, then push will be delivered when device becomes online.

Moreover, for iOS push-message is just a notification for a user, not for an application!

Simple case will illustrate it: 
Assume that push is received when the application is turned off. In that case, notification for the user will occur. But, application will receive data from push, only if user taps on that notification! If user will tap on application's icon, then data will not be received.

So techically, push is delivered to the iOS device and application is started, but data is not delivered.

**UrbanAirhip with APN and Helium**

You can consider to implement your own transport for pushes. MQTT seems to be a good option.
But in this case, you have to deal with keepalives, device sleeps and battery optimisations.
All that hard work is already done by engineers from Apple, Google and UrbanAirship.

Depending on your business needs, it can be easier to adapt your architecture for existing solutions, then reimplement push-service again.

Take a closer look to UrbanAirship. In fact, C2DM has some limitations and sometimes timings for delivery of push-message is too big. Because of that UA has implemented their own transport - Helium, it works pretty good. Helium is a paid service, but UA provides good SLA.

Answer (score 1):

I am suggesting for push notification IBM MQTT protocol. This fine enough for push notification. 
see the demo from https://github.com/tokudu/AndroidPushNotificationsDemo

Comment: Thanks for response! Thumb up first for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar where I had a database keep track of push queues to known subscribers and had reporting when failed. It was very simple and went something like this...

```
The schema was like so:

pushMessages
  messageID  , GUID, PK
  message , nvarchar (256),
  expires , datetime

messageQueues
  subscriberID , GUID, PK
  messageID , GUID PK

failedPushMessages
  subscriberID, GUID, PK
  messageID , GUID PK

(subscriber table omitted)
```

Once a client received the message successfully, the client would ping back to the push server and notify it via the unique queueItems ID that it received on the push notification. There would also be a daily database process that would check for expired push messages. When found, it would do a join on the queueMessages matching the messageID then remove them from the messagesQueues table and copy them to the failedPushMessages table.

This was very easy to understand and maintain but I don't have experience doing it another way.

Answer (score 0):

Push Services are an efficient and reliable way to alert your users. They allow even background applications to inform users of new information in real-time. Push Services are widely used for a variety of fields in mobile applications, such as weather updates, messaging services, mail notification, coupon services, and so on. Push Services are no longer optional but have become essential.